# Install FilePond in a Laravel project, how?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, file-upload, filepond

I'm developing my first Laravel based webapp. I need to upload some file so I decided to use [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) JavaScript library. I tried to install in my project via npm following the [documentation](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/installation/) so I did `npm i filepond --save` to install main library and repeated for some plugins... To use the library the documentations says to import with `import * as FilePond from 'filepond';` but where must I write these imports?
I wrote in `/resources/js/app.js` but it doesn't work...

Can anyone explain me how to insert correctly FilePond in a Laravel 6 project?

Comment: Could you plz add your webpack.mix.js file ?

Comment: I solved the problem, in my /resources/views/layout/app.blade.php (my main layout file) I had `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` in head section, now moved just before `</body>` and removed defer. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

#### To install FilePond in Laravel do the following

**In `/resources/js/app.js` import and assign it to global `window` object as follows:**

```js
import * as FilePond from 'filepond';

window.FilePond = FilePond;
```

**To import the styles in `/resources/css/main.css`:**

```css
@import "~filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
```

And now anywhere in your blade files you can simply get the `FilePond` instance.

Example using `AlpineJs` in blade file.

```html
<div x-data x-init="FilePond.create($refs.input);">
    <input type="file" x-ref="input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `/resources/js/app.js` I have:

```js
import * as FilePond from 'filepond';

require('./bootstrap');

$(document).ready(function () {
    // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
    console.log("Hi ");

    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
});
```

In `/resources/sass/app.scss` I have:

```css
// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';
```

In my `welcome.blade.php` I simply have added a file input tag with no actual form processing:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <input type="file">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After running `npm run dev` and loading my demo site, I get what I would expect.

[image: drag and drop screenshot]

Check out the docs on Laravel Mix for more details:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#working-with-scripts

Comment: I had all these steps, I included generated css and js files from `npm run dev`...

Comment: I ran through the documents and it seems to work for me. I'll update my answer with the detailed steps that I used on a fresh laravel.

Answer (score 0):

> FilePond is exposed as a module wrapped in a UMD. It can be added to a
>   project using Node Package Manager, from a CDN or by adding the files
>   manually.

**From a CDN**

```
<!-- add in <head> -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!--
The classic file input element we'll enhance to a file pond
-->
<input type="file" 
       class="filepond"
       name="filepond"
       multiple
       data-max-file-size="3MB"
       data-max-files="3" />


<!-- add before </body> -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-encode/dist/filepond-plugin-file-encode.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size/dist/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation/dist/filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></script>

/*
If you want to preview images, you need to register the Image Preview plugin
*/
<script>
FilePond.registerPlugin(

    // encodes the file as base64 data
  FilePondPluginFileEncode,

    // validates the size of the file
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,

    // corrects mobile image orientation
    FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,

    // previews dropped images
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);

// Select the file input and use create() to turn it into a pond
FilePond.create(
    document.querySelector("input[name='filepond']")
);
</script>
```

Comment: I know I can use CDN to get needed JavaScript and CSS files but I'd like to use npm and Laravel Mix to manage all libraries and components that I'll use during development...